# Angular with json-server post entities without ID

Tags: json, angular, lodash, angular7, json-server

I'm developing an angular project with the mock server json-server. GET is working correctly, but now I'm having some problems with POST.
I've defined this file `interventi.json` with these data:

```
{
    "interventi":[
        {
            "codice": "123",
            "codiceUso": 897,
            "dataIntervento": "21-06-2019",
            "dataInserimento": "24-06-2019",
            "cooperativa": "Example",
            "puntoVendita": "Example",
            "tipiAttivita": [
                "Prelievo",
                "Sanzione"
            ],
            "organoCompetente": "Ex"
        },
        {
            "codice": "456",
            "codiceUso": 823764,
            "dataIntervento": "24-06-2019",
            "dataInserimento": "29-06-2019",
            "cooperativa": "Example 2",
            "puntoVendita": "Example 2",
            "tipiAttivita": [
                "Prelievo"
            ],
            "organoCompetente": "Ex"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to post this json:

```
{  
   "codice":"a7spx",
   "codiceUso":"123",
   "dataIntervento":"2019-06-21T12:58:09.345Z",
   "cooperativa":"2",
   "puntoVendita":2,
   "tipiAttivita":[  
      "Attivita 1",
      "Attivita 2"
   ],
   "organoCompetente":3,
   "dataInserimento":"2019-06-21T12:58:09.345Z"
}
```

but it's giving me 500 internal server error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at Function.createId (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\json-server\lib\server\mixins.js:47:39)
>       at Function.insert (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\lodash-id\src\index.js:47:49)
>       at C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4374:28
>       at arrayReduce (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:683:21)
>       at baseWrapperValue (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4373:14)
>       at LodashWrapper.wrapperValue (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9052:14)
>       at create (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\json-server\lib\server\router\plural.js:225:50)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at next (C:\Users\Marina\coop-workspace\wqrng\web\src\main\angular\wqrng\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)"

I've followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d) to do post, and saw that field `id` is not mandatory, but server is complaining. If I add `id` field in my json, it works correctly. But I don't want id in my entities, is there a way to disable this behaviour?

**EDIT**

```
// Return incremented id or uuid
// Used to override lodash-id's createId with utils.createId
function createId(coll) {
  var _ = this;
  var idProperty = _.__id();
  if (_.isEmpty(coll)) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    var id = _(coll).maxBy(idProperty)[idProperty];

    // Increment integer id or generate string id
    return _.isFinite(id) ? ++id : nanoid(7);
  }
}
```

Comment: post `Function.createId`code

Comment: @MaihanNijat posted, but I can't change it, it's from json-server library.

Comment: If you cannot edit server side, then check if id is there pass it if not pass dummy data in id field.

Comment: As I said, if I add an id field to my json it is posted correctly, but I don't want to, my entity has to be without id. I'm looking for a way to disable this limit.

Comment: You cannot if you cannot change server side. The requirement is on server side not front end to fix it.

Comment: The server is mock! It's json-server library. I'm asking if there's some setting than can be changed to change its behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any id other then default "id" you have explicitly configure it using json-server CLI.

```
--id, -i           Set database id property (e.g. _id)         [default: "id"]
```

Check following link

https://github.com/typicode/json-server#cli-usage

Comment: Hi, thank you. But what if I have different files with different entities and they have different ids? Like, entity "User" has property "name" as id, entity "Course" has "code" as id, and so on...